# Jquery - Assign sibling Element with closest anchor link

Tags: jquery

I have a page of dynamically loading divs with titles, and links.

I'm trying to grab the link from each of the elements and assign it to a previous span / title / image.  I'm having trouble getting this to only use the anchor text within the same parent instead of returning all (in this case both) of the links?

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  jQuery(function($) {
    $('.ancestors').find('.bigp').each(function() {
      let link = $(this).find('a.mylink').attr('href');
      console.log(link);
      $('span.newlink').wrap('<a href="' + link + '"></a>');

    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body class="ancestors">body (great-grandparent)
  <div style="width:500px;" class="bigp">div (grandparent)
    <ul>ul (direct parent)
      <li>li (child)
        <span class="newlink">google pic</span>
      </li>
      <li class="findme"><a class="mylink" href="https://google.com">google</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div style="width:500px;" class="bigp">div (grandparent)
    <ul>ul (direct parent)
      <li>li (child)
        <span class="newlink">yahoo pic</span>
      </li>
      <li class="findme"><a class="mylink" href="https://yahoo.com">yahoo</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: `$('span.newlink')` doesn't consider that it's inside the `.bigp` loop, so looks globally - use the same syntax as you have for .find("a.mylink") -> `$(this).find("span.newline").wrap...`

Comment: I'm confused - what's your expected outcome?

Comment: Thanks Freedomn-m! Brilliant.